# Django: Clean method not picking up the submitted file

Tags: django

General file processing in my form works fine (on save/edit). But I cannot get file information when I access the file in the clean/validation method. Can you please help :)

forms.py

```
class BatchForm(ModelForm):

    csv_file = FileField(label='CSV File')
    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ('project', 'name', 'csv_file', 'filename')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
            super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


def clean(self):         
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        csv_file = cleaned_data.get("csv_file", False)
        print("file: ", csv_file)
        # csv_file prints None
```

I tried printing csv_file but I got None as output

My template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
  {{ form.as_table }}
</table>
</form>
```

My view:

```
def create_batch(request):
    form = BatchForm(request.POST or None, request=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        form.save_batch(request=request, create_batch_flag=True)
        return redirect('list_batch_url')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `request.FILES` as `request` into your form (which you subsequently drop on the floor, so to speak):

```
form = BatchForm(request.POST or None, request=request.FILES)
```

You probably mean

```py
form = BatchForm(
   data=(request.POST or None),
   files=(request.FILES or None),
   request=request,
)
```

Comment: This was the fastest fix I ever received. Better than my last 1 hour on Google. Thanks again AKX :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!